# Trouble installing pthreads in Windows

Tags: php, php-pthread

**PHP Version:** 7.4.5

I am running a thread-safe version of PHP becuase after doing `php -i|findstr "Thread"` I get:

```
Thread Safety => enabled
Thread API => Windows Threads
```

I downloaded the newest version pthreads (3.1.6) from: https://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/pthreads/3.1.6/ (I tried both the 32 and 64 bit versions).

I put the `pthreadVC2.dll` file in my `php\` directory and the `php_pthreads.dll` file in my `php\ext\` directory, and add the line `extension=php_pthreads.dll` to my `php.ini` file

Then after running any php command via the command-line (in my case, `php -v`) I get the following in the console when trying the 32 bit version:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'php_pthreads.dll' (tried: C:\xampp\php\ext\php_pthreads.dll (%1 is not a valid Win32 application.), C:\xampp\php\ext\php_php_pthreads.dll.dll (The specified module could not be found.)) in Unknown on line 0

Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'php_pthreads.dll' (tried: C:\xampp\php\ext\php_pthreads.dll (%1 is not a valid Win32 application.), C:\xampp\php\ext\php_php_pthreads.dll.dll (The specified module could not be found.)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP 7.4.5 (cli) (built: Apr 14 2020 16:17:34) ( ZTS Visual C++ 2017 x64 )
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.4.0, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
```

And this error when trying the 64 bit version:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'php_pthreads.dll' (tried: C:\xampp\php\ext\php_pthreads.dll (The specified procedure could not be found.), C:\xampp\php\ext\php_php_pthreads.dll.dll (The specified module could not be found.)) in Unknown on line 0

Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'php_pthreads.dll' (tried: C:\xampp\php\ext\php_pthreads.dll (The specified procedure could not be found.), C:\xampp\php\ext\php_php_pthreads.dll.dll (The specified module could not be found.)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP 7.4.5 (cli) (built: Apr 14 2020 16:17:34) ( ZTS Visual C++ 2017 x64 )
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.4.0, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If anybody happens upon this, what solved it for me was fixing my `extension_dir` setting in my `php.ini` file to actually pull from the `ext` folder present in the same directory. That line was commented out so I think it's default was trying to grab extensions from `C:\php\ext`.